# How validate user is in the correct directory?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

Hey guys I'm writing a quick script, just before it enters the if block, I need to make sure the user is in the Documents folder.

if ($pwd -not $DocumentsPath)

thats the condition I used but I keep getting an error that states:

Unexpected token '-not' in expression or statement.
At line:12 char:14

Unexpected token 'DocumentsPath' in expression or statement.
At line:12 char:19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want the `-not` operator, that operator is for doing this like turning a `$false` in to a `$true`. What you want is "Not Equal" or `-ne`.

```
if ($pwd -ne $DocumentsPath)
```

[Here is a list of the operators](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html), to help you out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you must specify 'path' property

```
if($PWD.Path -ne $DocumentsPath) {...}
```

or

```
if(!$PWD.Path.Trim($DocumentsPath)) {...}
```